# How to shift contents referenced by numpy array names in python

Tags: python, numpy

In python, I have numpy arrays `a0`, `a1`, and `a2`, each of which refer to different contents. I want to shift the relations between the reference names and the referred objects, so that `a2` will now point to the content pointed by `a1` before, and `a1` will now point to the content pointed by `a0` before. Then, I want to let `a0` to point to a new content.

To be more specific, I want to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a2=np.array([1,2,3,4])
a1=np.array([10,20,30,40])
a0=np.array([8,8,8,8]) 
a2=a1
a1=a0
# I want to assign new values to a0[0], a0[1], .., without affecting a1.
```

Can I do it without copying values (e.g. by `np.copy`) and without memory reallocation (e.g. by `del` and `np.empty`)?

Comment: Why do you need to reuse the `a0` array?  And where do the new values come from?

Comment: What it comes down to is that you want both an unchanged `a0` array, and a modified version of it.  The fact that you are reusing the names ('shifting') doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use tuple unpacking to exchanging values kindaof like the `a,b=b,a`

```
In [183]: a2=np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...: a1=np.array([10,20,30,40])
     ...: a0=np.array([8,8,8,8]) 
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [184]: 


In [185]: a2,a1=np.copy(a1),np.copy(a0)

In [186]: a0
Out[186]: array([8, 8, 8, 8])

In [187]: a1
Out[187]: array([8, 8, 8, 8])

In [188]: a2
Out[188]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

You are free to point `a0` where ever you want and i dont think you can create get away with  changing `a0` and not affecting `a1` without `np.copy` or something else like `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: By that `a0` and `a1` will point to the same contend in memory, so changing `a0` will also change `a1`. Eventually you want to discard `a2` and create a new array so I thing there is no way around copying the content of `a0` you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking is not possible without making a copy of `a0`, otherwise `a0` and `a1` will be pointing to the same object and changing `a0` will change `a1`. So you should do this:

```
a2 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a1 = np.array([10,20,30,40])
a0 = np.array([8,8,8,8]) 

a2 = a1
a1 = a0.copy()

# let's change a0
a0[0] = 9

# check
a0
Out[31]: array([9, 8, 8, 8])

a1
Out[32]: array([8, 8, 8, 8])

a2
Out[33]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```